# azure google sign in showing blank white page

Tags: angularjs, cordova, azure, ionic-framework, google-signin

Here is my code for google sign in with azure.

I have set up everything needed to use the google sign in including my authorized callback urls

https://myAzureSite.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/google/callback

and authorized javascript origins

https://myAzureSite.azurewebsites.net

I have also followed the instructions and enabled the social api and put the client id and client secret into the azure authentication settings for google. The content security policy meta tag is also there in my index file.

After researching some more I found this error on my application logs... something about the input not being valid

**Application logs**

```
2017-07-19T16:09:28  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service.
2017-07-19T16:09:36  PID[5300] Critical    System.FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. 
   at System.Convert.FromBase64_Decode(Char* startInputPtr, Int32 inputLength, Byte* startDestPtr, Int32 destLength)
   at System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength)
   at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
   at Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication.ModuleUtils.ParseKeyString(String keyString)
   at Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication.CryptoHelper.get_Default()
   at Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication.IdentityProviderBase.<RedirectToLoginPageAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication.IdentityProviderBase.<TryHandleProtocolRequestAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication.EasyAuthModule.<OnBeginRequestAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication.HttpModuleDispatcher.<DispatchAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
2017-07-19T16:09:36  PID[5300] Information Sending response: 500.79 Internal Server Error
2017-07-19 16:09:03 SCANNIN GET /.auth/login/google session_mode=token&X-ARR-LOG-ID=a0c71b7f-1ba1-4c70-b28e-053c0e2792ac 443 - 205.185.209.163 Mozilla/5.0+Google ARRAffinity=9d2a904ebce60f45ea468ce406b610510a42678c8d3f0cd761756aef31b3c514 - scannin.azurewebsites.net 500 79 2147500037 329 1039 15
2017-07-19 16:09:10 ~1SCANNIN GET /Microsoft.Mobile.Management/tables api-version=2014-11-01&_=1500480350552&X-ARR-LOG-ID=4340640e-40e4-40ea-97c0-dd4ead98d0ce 443 - 70.37.57.58 Mozilla/5.0+(Macintosh;+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10_12_5)+AppleWebKit/603.2.4+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Version/10.1.1+Safari/603.2.4 - https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/bd5771bb-237c-4508-bf66-419541298fd0/resourceGroups/ScanIn/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/ScannIn/extensions/Microsoft.Mobile.Management/tables?api-version=2014-11-01&_=1500480350552 scannin.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 1715 2611 31
```

login code

```
 client.login("google").done(function (results) {
     alert("You are now logged in as: " + results.userId);
}, function (err) {
     alert("Error: " + err);
});
```

[image: Error image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Silly mistake on my part, this past month I have been trying to add custom authentication to my application but with no avail. During this process I added a website signing key to my application settings. This is what caused the error.